# Camunda Rest API Basic Authenication on Heroku Deployment - Tomcat Webapp

Tags: tomcat, heroku, bpmn, camunda, webapp-runner

I'm using the below Github repo to deploy Camunda to Heroku but it does not enable the Rest API.

https://github.com/plexiti/camunda-webapp-tomcat-standalone-heroku

From my research, I think this will be done by editing the pom.xml file which is using the Webapp-Runner repo which talks about using the following parameters.

--enable-basic-auth
--basic-auth-pw
--basic-auth-user

Documentation is here https://github.com/heroku/webapp-runner/blob/master/README.md

Here is the pom.xml file

https://github.com/plexiti/camunda-webapp-tomcat-standalone-heroku/blob/master/pom.xml

All this is a bit above my experience level and I would appreciate any help from the community.

Thanks in Advance